# javascript - iterating over bidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I am trying to write a javascript program that renders an 8x8 grid of dirt tiles on an HTML5 canvas. However, when I run this code it throws up error messages when running the `draw_terrain()` function and it appears to be a problem with the `blockArray.length` component. Can someone explain to me how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
//Define initial canvas variables and images

var canvas;
var ctx;
var WIDTH = 800;
var HEIGHT = 800;
var dirt = new Image();
dirt.src = 'dirt.png';

//Function called to initialise canvas variables and run draw on interval

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    return setInterval(draw, 15);
}

//Function that generates an 8x8 Array called blockArray

function gen_terrain(){

var blockArray = new Array(8);

for(var i=0; i<blockArray.length; i++) {
    blockArray[i] = new Array(8);
    for(var j=0; j<blockArray[i].length; j++){
        blockArray[i][j] = 0;
    };
};
}

//Function that returns a random number between a min and max

function randomRange (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function draw_terrain(){
    for(var i=0; i<blockArray.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<blockArray[i].length; j++){
            ctx.drawImage(dirt,(n-1)*32,(j-1)*32);
        };
    };
}

function draw(){
    draw_terrain();
}

gen_terrain();
init();
```

Comment: `//Function that generates an 8x8 Array called blockArray` ...and then throws it away. Variables are function scoped.

Comment: `blockArray` is declared as a variable inside of the scope of `gen_terrain`. It is not accessible from the `draw_terrain` method.

Comment: Ah okay, how would I make it global?

Comment: I don't understand the question... You already have global variables declared. Surely... Oh I see, copypasta strikes again!

Comment: Like you made the others global, you don't even need the function in the first place, you can just create the array at the top

Comment: Also, it's generally considered better to declare an empty array with `var arry = [];` You can still access/assign any index of the array. You could, after declaring an empty array, assign to it like so: `arry[999] = 'redrum';`

Comment: Why did you declare the array when you never really use it anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, as other people have explained is that the variable you are using the build the array will not exist by the time the draw occurs.   Just place your array declaration outside of the function and your issue will go away.

See comment below:

```
function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    return setInterval(draw, 15);
}

//Function that generates an 8x8 Array called blockArray
var blockArray = []; // <== has to be global (outside function).

function gen_terrain(){
    // Not here -> var blockArray = [];
    for(var i=8; i--;) {
        blockArray[i] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    };
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UWL8V/1/)

Comment: Any kind of Explanation would greatly improve the use of this "answer". Also you don't need to copy the weep limes of code which absolutely have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: OK, well.  The real answer is that you have to learn about scope, specifically, variable scope in order to program in javascript.  A link: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Just fyi, I'm not the OP and I know very well how js works. I just dislike answers which throw in some random lines of code without explanation.

Comment: I was trying to improve my answer as you suggested, thought that link and explanation might help.  I have a big comment in the code pointing out the new and old location of the problem, thought that was helpful also.